# Amazon ec2 user Linux Lampp Phpmyadmin showing blank page

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

i followed this tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

after that, i tried

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

it installed the phpmyadmin successfully, but when i visit http://123.4.5.67/phpmyadmin

i even tested to make a sample http://123.4.5.67/phpinfo.php,

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

shows php version and infos, means php is working.
i also tried: `mysql -u root -p` , mysql works perfectly.

now the only thing left for me to do is a mysql database GUI, the phpmyadmin, which is showing blank page.

> Am i missing something? whats next after installing phpmyadmin? is
>   there anything else i have to configure?

Comment: you have to configure phpmyadmin I guess

Comment: that, i do not know where

Comment: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: it is not so hard as you think. you can try use bitnami ami for aws. but you should understand how ssh works then,if this one is hard for you, not sure if bitami ami would be the better choice to you :-(

Comment: by the way, did you configure apache to redirect alias `phpmyadmin` to phpmyadmin folder?

Comment: have you tried amazon web service?

Comment: yes I did some tests for my projects. bitnami ami was easy to run.

Comment: I would suggest [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) instead. Easier to configure and use

Comment: @Machavity sure it could be easier to set up in this case.

Comment: @Machavity but im doing this in command prompt. does this somehow connect to my web server?

Comment: find out where phpmyadmin was installed. look in `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` to see if phpmyadmin folder exists. if it doesn't, then you need to find it, and move it there. or, as previously mentioned, configure apache to redirect alias `phpmyadmin` to the location of phpmyadmin

Comment: @KenDanTinio It can connect to your MySQL instance running on your server. You will need to open port 3306 in the AWS firewall to your IP

Comment: yes i just did, it can connect niceeeee

Comment: but still the question, stands

Comment: Any hint in the web server error log?